# Bindable property not working in user control wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have User Control and create DepedencyProperty "ItemSource" inside that user control like this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(DataGridFilterDetail),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged)));

public IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
   get
   {
      return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
   }
   set
   {
      SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
      NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemsSource");
   }
}

static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var control = sender as DataGridFilterDetail;
   if (control != null)
   {
      control.OnItemsSourceChanged((IEnumerable)e.OldValue(IEnumerable)e.NewValue);
   }
}

void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
{
    // Remove handler for oldValue.CollectionChanged
    var oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

    if (null != oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged)
    {
        oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged);
    }
        // Add handler for newValue.CollectionChanged (if possible)
    var newValueINotifyCollectionChanged = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    if (null != newValueINotifyCollectionChanged)
    {
        newValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged);
    }
 }

void newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.NewItems == null)
     {
         TotalCount = 0;
     }
     else
     {
         TotalCount = e.NewItems.Count;
     }
 }
```

And then i bind "ItemSource" into ItemSource of my DataGrid inside UserControl like this.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF.Controls.DataGridFilterDetail" x:Name="dataGridFilterDetail" .../>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=dataGridFilterDetail,Path=ItemsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
</UserControl>
```

and then i using this user control inside my view.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.View.MyView" ..
<UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:MyViewModel x:Key="myViewModel" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <custom:DataGridFilterDetail ItemsSource="{Binding GridItemCollections, Source={StaticResource myViewModel}}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

inside MyView.cs Constructor i set my view datacontext :

```
public MyView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myViewModel= (MyViewModel)this.Resources["myViewModel"];
            this.DataContext = myViewModel;
        }
```

on myViewModel i create property "GridItemCollections" like this

```
 private ObservableCollection<myCustomClass> gridItemCollections;
 public ObservableCollection<myCustomClass> GridItemCollections
 {
     get { return gridItemCollections; }
     set
     {
         gridItemCollections = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("GridItemCollections");
     }
 }

 public void AddNewGridRow()
 {
    GridItemCollections.Add(CurrentDetail);
 }
```

now the problem is, why grid inside user control not updating when i modify "GridItemCollections" on my view model?is there something that i missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's happening in `OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged` in your DataGridFilterDetail control? It doesn't seem to be necessary. You also do not need to raise the PropertyChanged event in the dependency property setter. A UserControl does usually not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged i set new collection for my user control like this :                                                                                  var control = sender as DataGridFilterDetail;
            if (control != null)
            {
                control.OnItemsSourceChanged((IEnumerable)e.OldValue, (IEnumerable)e.NewValue);
            }                                                                                                                I know i do not need raise PropertyChanged, i'm kind a desperate :( so i try those.

Comment: hi Clemens, i already add OnItemsSourceChanged code into my question

Comment: hi clemens, i already add the rest of the code into my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73924/discussion-between-selalu-ingin-belajar-and-clemens).

Comment: hi clemens, i already add updated question

Comment: Looks still ok, except that you wouldn't need to set `Source={StaticResource myViewModel}` if you set the DataContext to that view model instance anyway. Binding would go to the DataContext object by default. Now I assume (as haven't shown that too) you actually call `myViewModel.AddNewGridRow` somewhere? All that works for me.

Comment: Are you sure you have only single instance of your viewmodel? Sometimes usercontrols creates its own instance of viewmodel like yours and then parent view assign different viewmodel instance to usercontrol's datacontext.

Comment: This is the kind of question that is _easily_ solved when the questioner includings [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, and which is nearly impossible to solve otherwise. Please provide a good code example.